# media queries for desktop 1024 vs ipad

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I need to set my site on desktop (1024 * 768) and ipad, but I can not separate his Vizualization.

I'm using in Ipad:

```
@ media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width : 1010px)
```

and desktop:

```
@ media (min-width: 1020px)
```

its Works in Firefox, but not Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to target specific devices, it's arguably better to set appropriate breakpoints specific to your layout. That is, gradually narrow your browser and observe the points at which *this particular design* needs to reflow. Then set styles that apply to those points, and let each device receive whatever layout works best within its dimensions.

So, in the head of your page, I recommend you place this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

and then in your style sheet, use something like this (the numbers are arbitrary):

```
/* default styles, perhaps for basic mobiles and older browsers */

/* end default styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) { }

@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 1024px) { }

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) { }

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) { }
```

There are so many combinations of this that the above is just a rough example. You don't always need max and/or min. It depends on the layout.

There's also an argument for using ems instead of px, but I won't go there for now. :)

Comment: That makes sense. But what about the device pixel ration? Example: @media only screen 
and (device-width: 320px)
and (device-height: 640px) 
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)

Comment: Yep, you can target those to if you wish. I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Well, your list above does not bring the pixel-ratio item (and therefore does it imply to be 1?). Should we have three list as yours? one with no information (like yours), one with ratio 1, one ratio 2 and ratio 3 and so forth? I am actually trying to build my "grid" as we speak, and it's very confusing. Some desktops (like libraries) have 1024 PC... i gues IPad is also 1024...

Comment: `your list above does not bring the pixel-ratio item (and therefore does it imply to be 1?)`. It's just an example list, based on the settings you might want. The examples above are just based on the screen size, but yes, you can also refine the media queries by also specifying specific pixel densities. Again, don't worry what pixel counts each device has. Just make sure the layout looks OK at the various screen widths, as make changes where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just cascade down?

`@media screen and (max-width : 1024px){ /*Styles*/ }`

`@media screen and (max-device-width : 768px){ /*Styles*/ }`

1024x768 is iPad size anyway.